# Android start activity while download video

Tags: android, video

This is my code:

```
protected void loadvide(final Chan channel) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Rtmpdump dump = new Rtmpdump();
                    dump.parseString(channel.getUrl());
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                         startActivity(new Intent(this,VideoViewDemo.class));
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }.start();  

    }
```

The function to my code is: First this part to the code:

```
"Rtmpdump dump = new Rtmpdump();
 dump.parseString(channel.getUrl());"
```

begin download the video, and then the thread, start the activity "VideoViewDemo.class"

But I have a problem, because this code:

```
"Rtmpdump dump = new Rtmpdump();
 dump.parseString(channel.getUrl());"
```

download the video, but never finish the download, "**this is the correct function for this code**".

And as never just downloaded the video, so never start the activity "VideoViewDemo.class".

I would like start activity "VideoViewDemo.class" while downloading video.

Comment: start the activity and in its onCreate() download the video .. !

Comment: thanks!! but it's not possible because is required the parameters "Chan channel" to download video